# How can I display an animated gif in React Native Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

I search about it and find the solution like fresco but i can't find any solutions for expo. Please give me solution about it.

<Image style={{width:38,height:38}}
source={require('../assets/images/avatar.gif')}/>

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet you have is correct.

Import Statement

```js
import { Image } from "react-native";
```

For Remote URIs:

```js
<Image source={{ uri: REMOTE_GIF }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
```

For Local gif files:

```js
<Image source={require('./assets/2.gif')} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />
```

Note: For local files, just make sure that the path to that file from that component is correct. Maybe that is causing the issue for you.

Here's a [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/gif-example) that has both the implementation. Tested this for Android, iOS and Web.

Comment: is gif supported in expo or not?

Comment: Yes, its supported. As I said, The Snack link that I added in my answer has the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported `Image` from React Native:

```
import {Image} from "react-native";
```

Answer (score 0):

React Native also includes a built-in [ActivityIndicator](https://reactnative.dev/docs/activityindicator).

```js
import {ActivityIndicator, View} from 'react-native';

const App = () => (
  <View>
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#00ff00" />
  </View>
);
```